# Reference field in the Interface subclass (Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin, interface, field

Is there a possible way to reference interface's static field in the class, which implements interface without importing, or calling referencing to interface explicitly.

I want to do like this:

```
interface Globals {
    companion object {
        val mc get() = Bloomware.mc
        val cPlayer get() = mc.player!!
        val cWorld get() = mc.world!!

        fun sendPacket(p: Packet<*>?) {
            mc.networkHandler!!.sendPacket(p)
        }
    }
}
```

(Class user)

```
object ResourceCancel : Module(), Globals {
    @Subscribe
    private fun onPacketSend(event: EventPacket.Send) {
        cPlayer.jump() // call this
}
```

I know it's possible in Java, but i can't repeat the same in Kotlin

Comment: You mention subclassing. Where is subclassing involved?

Comment: oh, im sorry, forgot to add "implement"

Comment: You can't just use `cPlayer` in Java; you have to specify the interface explicitly, i.e. `Globals.cPlayer`. Same in Kotlin.

Comment: @k314159 Well, you could just use `cPlayer` if it were a static field in Java rather than a getter method. But since in Kotlin properties are really functions and not fields, the pattern doesn't translate to Kotlin.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I disagree: this one compiles: https://ideone.com/hyMas0 and this one doesn't: https://ideone.com/yjxpxi

Comment: @k314159 I'm talking about fields, not methods. Sorry, I think I edited my comment to clarify while you were making the example.

Comment: Ah, yes I see - I saw the properties in the code above and thought about functions, which is what properties are.

Comment: In any case, this looks like bad design. It is similar to the [constant interface antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface) and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to do this in Kotlin.

The closest I think you could get is to define your global stuff at the top level in its own package, and then import that package`.*` in files where you want to access them.

```
package com.foo.globals

val mc get() = Bloomware.mc
val cPlayer get() = mc.player!!
val cWorld get() = mc.world!!

fun sendPacket(p: Packet<*>?) {
    mc.networkHandler!!.sendPacket(p)
}
```

```
import com.foo.globals.*

object ResourceCancel : Module() {
    @Subscribe
    private fun onPacketSend(event: EventPacket.Send) {
        cPlayer.jump() // call this
}
```

Comment: This is good because it avoids the [constant interface antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface) that the OP's Java equivalent exhibits. However, while I see that you are copying the OP's definitions of these vals, the OP should be aware that every time you reference `mc` you will be calling the `Bloomware.mc` property. Every time you reference `cPlayer` you will be checking for null. If these are meant to be like Java fields, lose the `get()`.

Comment: thank you. However, i suppose there is no way to avoid imports. Because the problem i stumbled upon is: once i do that thing, and define my global fields, i have to import everything by hand in each class i'm using these fields. Not convenient, but whatever

Comment: @OffeeX, Kotlin's design philosophy is to prioritize code robustness over conciseness/convenience. There are a lot of things you can do in Java that you can't do in Kotlin for this reason. You can read the link in the comment above about why you should avoid doing this in Java as well.